# How to send mail to admin from individual mail I'd in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm Working on Employee Management System Project, There is three type of user HR, Director and Employee. I want to send record mail to Director mail I'd from Employees individual email ID. How I can implement this feature, I'm working in Django.

I'm trying to implement using Django send_mail() function but there is password providing issue, we can't provide email password for all employees. I want to know how i can implement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.